# Android & iPhone apps design methodologies

Tags: android, iphone

When designing mobile applications, I usually find a few issues I have to deal with and, though I have found general guidelines to do it, I have not found concrete solutions or methodologies to do it.

My first question is where to start designing. I have read that a good idea is start designing for mdpi and then scale into the other resolutions. But what resolution should I start with?

When I deliver the resources, can I use the pictures I have delivered for mdpi for the iPhone app too, and the xhdpi (mdpi*2.0) for the retina version, or the iPhone version should be somewhere between mdpi and hdpi?

Another question that comes to my mind is that, if I design starting at mdpi, sometimes it's necessary to make a picture that takes just 1px height, or paint a border of a box that takes just 1px height too. What happens when I have to deliver to ldpi (1px*0.75)? Does it make sense to have something that takes just 1px in a retina version of a resource?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found it to be better to start the design using the most high resolution textures. and design the xhdpi devices first (like Samsung Galaxy S3). and the go back to the lower resolution devices such as Galaxy S2 an so on....

The reason for that is that it's much more preferred to scale your textures down then to stretch them for a higher resolution. all this is in case when you have only one set of texture for all of you devices and the re-sizing is performed automatically by the platform.

Comment: That's what I thought first, but then I have to be careful not to make anything that takes just 1px, what happens when you scale down borders that only takes 1px? I think it's not accurate at all and the application will look differently in different phones.

Comment: I never work with pixels, only with dots per inch (dp). and I guess this is the most import work methodologie that you have to implement.

Comment: Of course, but that's once you're programming with Android, I'm talking about the pictures themselves, and that's before programming anything.

Comment: personally when I use textures of one pixel then i use wrap_content for height and width and it look fine on all screens.

Comment: But you use the same resource in every resolution?

Comment: yes in most cases... unless i see that it really looks wrong.

Comment: That's not what Android recommends to do, I'm trying to deliver different resources (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) for Android, and for iPhone (non-retina, retina), and all the questions I ask are related to that.